# Parallel animations in React Native Reanimated 2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

How do I animate two nodes -- a parent and a child -- together concurrently in React Native Reanimated 2.

I guess I would have used `transition.together` in the previous versions but I can't find an alternative in the newer version.